# Node Net.Socket Character Encoding Issue

Tags: node.js, sockets, terminal, character-encoding, telnet

I'm connecting via telnet to an Cisco codec SX20.
My socket connects then gets: `��\u0018�� ��#��\'` after connecting. I'm expecting something similar to `Password:` or `login:`. Other devices I connect to with node's net.socket work fine though. This is the only chunk that I get; it always *looks* the same.
I've tried a ton node encoding implementations (native and iconv) - nothing readable. Other clients work fine, like putty (utf8 encoding) or telnet command (auto-discovered?).

Some results: https://gist.github.com/below9k/4dbae508031d586ed7719958b425552c

-- RESOLUTION / EDIT:
I eventually resolved this using https://github.com/blinkdog/telnet-stream
Apparently this unit wanted some minor telnet negotiations before cooperating.

```
const telnetInput = new TelnetInput()
const telnetOutput = new TelnetOutput()
telnetInput.on('do', function (option) {
    telnetOutput.writeWont(option)
})
telnetInput.on('will', function (option) {
    telnetOutput.writeDont(option)
})
telnetInput.on('data', Meteor.bindEnvironment((data) => {
    console.log(data.toString('utf8'))
}))
socket.pipe(telnetInput)
telnetOutput.pipe(socket)
```

console.log returns `login:` - yay

My understand is that I sent the unit a couple of standardized bits of info (more info in the repo above) and that makes it work.

Answer (score 0):

I eventually resolved this using https://github.com/blinkdog/telnet-stream
Apparently this unit wanted some minor telnet negotiations before cooperating.

```
const telnetInput = new TelnetInput()
const telnetOutput = new TelnetOutput()
telnetInput.on('do', function (option) {
    telnetOutput.writeWont(option)
})
telnetInput.on('will', function (option) {
    telnetOutput.writeDont(option)
})
telnetInput.on('data', Meteor.bindEnvironment((data) => {
    console.log(data.toString('utf8'))
}))
socket.pipe(telnetInput)
telnetOutput.pipe(socket)
```

console.log returns `login:` - yay

My understand is that I sent the unit a couple of standardized bits of info (more info in the repo above) and that makes it work.

below9k